# In VBScript, I can not stop my loop from repeating

Tags: vbscript

I have looked hard to resolve this issue, but I am coming up short.

Here is my code:

```
'attempts and completions loop
    'attempts
    do
        do
            Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many attempts did " & QB & " throw: "
            attempts = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
            if IsNumeric(attempts) then
                attempts = CInt(attempts)
            else
                Wscript.StdOut.Write "You did not enter a number. Please try again."
            end if
        loop while IsNumeric(attempts) = false

        'completions
        do
            Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many completed passes did " & QB & " throw for: "
            completions = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
            if IsNumeric(completions) then
                attempts = CInt(completions)
            else
                Wscript.StdOut.Write "You did not enter a number. Please try again."
            end if
        loop while (completions) = false
    if attempts > completions then
        exit do
    else
        Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Completions can not be more that attempts please try again."
    end if
    loop while attempts < completions
```

When I enter more completions than attempts, I get my desire result. But when I enter more attempts than completes it will still loop through this code. Can I please get some assistance.

Comment: I assume that the missing IsNumeric for (completions) is just a copy/paste typo?

Also, when the program unexpectedly loops, does it also display the "Completions cannot be more..." message or does it just loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind my comment...I see it now.  In the loop for Completions, you are setting the attempts variable when you should be setting the completions variable.

```
if IsNumeric(completions) then
            attempts = CInt(completions)
```

So when you're comparing, attempts is always blank or whatever you've initialized it to.

Standard copy/paste error  :)

Comment: You do also still have a missing IsNumeric

Comment: Thank you so much. It has been a long day. Lol

Comment: I am still having the same problem. No matter what number I enter in for attempts and completions it will proceed to my next prompt not allowing me to retry my inputs.

Comment: Sorry, what's it doing now?  Can you post an example of the output?  and maybe the latest code?